# Remove Y-value in broken bar plot python

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

[image]

Hi all!
I'm using matplotlib to create the upper plot.
How can I remove the two 10.00 and have it only once?

Comment: check [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/broken_axis.html)

Comment: Is there a reason you want the break at all?  The y-range for those bars is relatively small and in general, breaking the y-axis is a bad idea (you lose the value of having a bar plot... your eye can easily compare sizes of bars, but if you break the axis you deceive the eye).  If it were me, I'd just get rid of the y-axis break altogether.

Comment: I break the y-axis because I need to have the same scale for all my sample and in some cases I have higher values.